# javascript - How to get "writable" HTML components?

Tags: javascript, html, input, firefox-addon, textarea

My problem is that I want to create a Firefox AddOn, and I need to extract from the HTML document every "writable" (I mean: `input`, `textarea` or other ways to write text) to work with its value.

I know the method `document.getElementByTagName()`, but the case is that i don't know how many tags to input text exist (or a webpage usually have on it) to refer them this way; or even if this problem can be solved otherwise.

I really appreciate any help or idea to do this efficently, so I can go forward with this project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have 2 possible tags: `textarea` and `input`. The problem is that with HTML5 the input tag has several kinds of types which you can insert text but you have also another ones that you can't (like submit or radio):

1. color
2. date
3. datetime
4. email
5. month
6. number
7. password
8. search
9. tel
10. text
11. time
12. url

You can use document.querySelectorAll function to retrieve those elements:

`document.querySelectorAll("textarea input[type=text] input[type=email]");`

Note that I have only include text and email in the selector but was just a sample mode. You should add all the types you think necessary retrieve.

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-type) you have all the possible types for input tag and the browser support of those, I recommend check out the documentation to have a better idea of what tags should be relevant for you.

Comment: Interesting, I'll read about that function, thank you. And if only exists these two tags, I think I can do this easily :)